# Adding 3 repeating columns to the end of my data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in the following format:

```
       0        1         2         3        4         5         6    
0  09.08.00  31.6875 -0.017442  17.10.00  59.1250  0.002119  24.10.00 ...  
1  10.08.00  31.7031  0.000492  18.10.00  59.1250  0.000000  25.10.00 ...
2  11.08.00  31.7656  0.001971  19.10.00  59.3125  0.003171  26.10.00 ...  
3  14.08.00  31.5625 -0.006394  20.10.00  59.5625  0.004215  27.10.00 ...  
4  15.08.00  31.5000 -0.001980  23.10.00  59.1250 -0.007345  30.10.00 ...  

       413       414     415       416  
0   0.004704  01.05.18  133.48 -0.034991  ......  
1  -0.001725  02.05.18  138.58  0.038208  ...... 
2  0.000247  03.05.18  141.56  0.021504   ......
3  0.000987  04.05.18  139.76 -0.012715   ......
4  0.000493  07.05.18  139.63 -0.000930   .......
```

As you can see the data is split into 3 columns for multiple groups (in this case tickers). Whats more is that the data I have is recorded over differing amounts of time. The first group for example may have 100 days of data the second only 25 and so on. This means we have different amounts of rows with data entries for each group.

I would like the end Data Frame to have 3 columns instead of 416. So I was thinking of somehow appending 3 columns at a time to an existing Data Frame. So the end result should look like this:

```
       0        1         2              
0  09.08.00  31.6875 -0.017442  
1  10.08.00  31.7031  0.000492  
2  11.08.00  31.7656  0.001971  
3  14.08.00  31.5625 -0.006394    
4  15.08.00  31.5000 -0.001980
5  17.10.00  59.1250  0.002119  
6  18.10.00  59.1250  0.000000  
7  19.10.00  59.3125  0.003171  
8  20.10.00  59.5625  0.004215  
9  23.10.00  59.1250 -0.007345
```

I hope this question is clear enough. How would I go about programming this using pandas etc. in Python? Thanks in advance for your answers

Sincerely,

Elias

Comment: Same question here

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I dont know where to start. I created a new Data Frame with only the 3 columns I want. I was looking at the documentation for concat but dont quite understand the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with multiindex create by modulo and integer divisions:

```
a = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [a % 3, a // 3]
df = df.stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
          0        1         2
0  09.08.00  31.6875 -0.017442
1  10.08.00  31.7031  0.000492
2  11.08.00  31.7656  0.001971
3  14.08.00  31.5625 -0.006394
4  15.08.00  31.5000 -0.001980
5  17.10.00  59.1250  0.002119
6  18.10.00  59.1250  0.000000
7  19.10.00  59.3125  0.003171
8  20.10.00  59.5625  0.004215
9  23.10.00  59.1250 -0.007345
```

Numpy solution is possible, but because there are some strings last is necessary converting to `float`s:

```
a = np.reshape(df.values,(len(df), -1, 3)).swapaxes(0,1).reshape(-1, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df[[1,2]] = df[[1,2]].astype(float)
print (df)
          0        1         2
0  09.08.00  31.6875 -0.017442
1  10.08.00  31.7031  0.000492
2  11.08.00  31.7656  0.001971
3  14.08.00  31.5625 -0.006394
4  15.08.00  31.5000 -0.001980
5  17.10.00  59.1250  0.002119
6  18.10.00  59.1250  0.000000
7  19.10.00  59.3125  0.003171
8  20.10.00  59.5625  0.004215
9  23.10.00  59.1250 -0.007345
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I will accept your answer when its possible!

Answer (score 1):

Short alternative with `pd.concat` + `np.split` functions (without mutating the initial dataframe `df`):

```
f = lambda df: df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T
new_df = pd.concat(map(f, np.split(df, range(3, df.columns.size, 3), axis=1)), ignore_index=True)
```